# MySQL said: #1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
  student.Student_Name
FROM
  `student`
GROUP BY
  student.Student_ID,
  teacher.Department_No IN (
    SELECT
      teacher.Department_No
    FROM
      `teacher`, `building`
    WHERE
      teacher.Department_No BETWEEN 1000
      AND 2999
    GROUP BY
      teacher.Department_No = (
        SELECT
          *
        FROM
          `building`
        WHERE
          building.Building_No IN ( '1', '2') 
      )
  ) LIMIT 0, 25
```

Comment: The subquery must return exactly one column.

Comment: I have never seen a group by modified with an in clause before but from a quick test it does syntax and execute but doesn't produce the results I would want.

Answer (score 0):

Your sql has two issues:

1. You need to use `IN` instead of `=` OR limit the subquery to only one record
2. You need to use a specify column instead of `*` in the subquery

use `IN`

```
teacher.Department_No IN (
        SELECT
          Department_No
        FROM
          `building`
        WHERE
          building.Building_No IN ( '1', '2') 
      )
```

use `LIMIT`

```
 teacher.Department_No = (
    SELECT
      Department_No
    FROM
      `building`
    WHERE
      building.Building_No IN ( '1', '2') 
    LIMIT 1
  )
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to select one column like deparment_id in subquery part

```
SELECT
  student.Student_Name
FROM
  `student`
GROUP BY
  student.Student_ID,
  teacher.Department_No IN (
    SELECT
      teacher.Department_No
    FROM
      `teacher`, `building`
    WHERE
      teacher.Department_No BETWEEN 1000
      AND 2999
    GROUP BY
      teacher.Department_No = (
        SELECT
          department_id
        FROM
          `building`
        WHERE
          building.Building_No IN ( '1', '2') 
      )
  ) LIMIT 0, 25
```